# power conception of a cloud kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, service, cloud, consumption

is it possible to know the power consumption of my Kubernetes deployed on a cloud (Ovh cloud) or another cloud?

I tried to use monitoring tools but they don't offer power consumption data because they need access to physical sensors and I had no way to access them on my k8s cloud service, I need to know if I have 20 applications running on my k8s, does it consume the same power as 50 running applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check tools like **Kepler** and **Scaphandre**, they provide solutions for tracking energy usage at the process, container, and Kubernetes pod levels.

[Exploring Kepler's potential](https://www.cncf.io/blog/2023/10/11/exploring-keplers-potentials-unveiling-cloud-application-power-consumption/)

[Introducing Kepler: Efficient power monitoring for Kubernetes](https://next.redhat.com/2023/08/22/introducing-kepler-efficient-power-monitoring-for-kubernetes/)

[How to measure energy consumption of Kubernetes applications with Scaphandre](https://www.scaleway.com/en/blog/how-to-measure-energy-consumption-applications-kubernetes/)